# Imported glb file not showing up right in Blender

Tags: 3d-view, import

[image]

I'm trying to import this adorable Bulbasaur into Blender for a personal project It has animations and textures included, and can only be downloaded in glb, usdz, and gitf.

When I download the glb file and open it in Bezel 3D (a AR prototyping software), it works perfectly, with textures intact and all the animations imported. However, when I try to import the file into Blender, I get these strange shapes. The whole hierarchy is there, but the mesh is all over. I tried all the other file types available, and I get the same problem every time.

What's happening and how I can bring the model and animations correctly into Blender?

My goal is to make some changes to Bulbasaur in Blender, then export the model and animations into Unity as fbx.

[Bulbasaur Pokemon [Animated]](https://skfb.ly/osVMv) by prozip is licensed under [Creative Commons Attribution](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/).